# Why does my code to USACO Silver Breed Counting not work?

Tags: c++, prefix-sum

This is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    freopen("bcount.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("bcount.out", "w", stdout);
    int n, q;
    cin >> n >> q;
    vector<int> holsteins(n);
    vector<int> guernseys(n);
    vector<int> jerseys(n);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        holsteins[i+1]=holsteins[i];
        guernseys[i+1]=guernseys[i];
        jerseys[i+1]=jerseys[i];
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        if (a==1) holsteins[i+1]++;
        else if (a==2) guernseys[i+1]++;
        else jerseys[i+1]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < q ; i++) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << holsteins[b]-holsteins[a-1] << " " << guernseys[b]-guernseys[a-1] << " " << jerseys[b]-jerseys[a-1] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it fails to pass the sample case and the official grader says that there was a runtime error or memory fail. I suspected it had something w/ input output but there wasn't. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code, assuming that it even compiles, because:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

This is a non-standard header file. On some C++ compilers the shown code won't even compile. Assuming that the shown code compiles:

```
    cin >> n >> q;
    vector<int> holsteins(n);
```

This input is not checked for validity. Invalid or negative input results in undefined behavior.

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        holsteins[i+1]=holsteins[i];
```

This results in undefined behavior when `i` is `n-1`, so `i+1` is `n`, and this assigns to `holsteins[n]`, which does not exist.

```
        guernseys[i+1]=guernseys[i];
        jerseys[i+1]=jerseys[i];
```

Same bug here, undefined behavior when accessing a nonexistent value in the vector.

```
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        if (a==1) holsteins[i+1]++;
```

Continuation/variation of the first bug. Invalid or negative input results in undefined behavior.

```
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << holsteins[b]-holsteins[a-1] << " " << guernseys[b]-
```

All of the above bugs, combined. Undefined behavior due to invalid or negative input, or due to access to nonexistent vector values (when `b` or `a` is `n` or greater).

Those are all the reason I could see why the shown code will not work correctly due to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much. Although, apart from the indexing issue the invalid inputs are not a problem. The problem statement (which I should have linked-I'm sorry) makes sure that no values are negative and a<=b.